# The most significant certification in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, certificate

I want to give myself a goal to learn WPF. Tell a certificate that must pass to be sure that I know WPF.

I'm interested in both free and paid certificates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know of only one certification exam for WPF:

**Exam 70-502: 
TS: Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5, Windows Presentation Foundation Application Development**

About this Exam
This exam is designed to test the candidate's knowledge on using Windows Presentation Foundation on the .NET  Framework 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-502&locale=en-us

**MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-502): Microsoft® .NET Framework 3.5—Windows® Presentation Foundation -**

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=12485&locale=en-us

Comment: These links are now dead. Potentially because the exams have been retired.

Answer (score 18):

I think there is a newer certification available. 
The focus is now not only WPF, also Forms and .Net

**Exam 70-511:
TS: Windows Applications Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4**

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-511&Locale=en-us

Comment: I checked and I don't see any prerequisite. Is it because they removed them for this certification ? I needed 70-536 before.

Comment: This exam has now been retired.

Comment: is there a replacement for this exam?

Comment: This link has all certification from Microsoft https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-list.aspx